# Query returns different result (is it index problem?)

Tags: sql, oracle

Query1

```sql
SELECT id FROM user
WHERE premiumYn='Y';
```

-> returns

```
|   id   |
| ------ |
|12345678|
|23456789|
|34567890|
```

So, then I query with

Query2

```sql
SELECT id, premiumYn FROM user
WHERE id IN (
12345678,
23456789,
34567890
);
```

-> returns

```
| id       | premiumYn |
| ---------| --------- |
| 12345678 |    N      |
| 23456789 |    Y      |
| 34567890 |    N      |
```

I expect all premiumYn to be 'Y'.

The `id` is pk of the table. The table is not indexed with `premiumYn`.
The `user` table has rowCount of 0.5 Billion. It's Oracle DB.

Which result should I trust?

Comment: If you're asking for assistance with potential data corruption, then we're going to need to see the real queries, the real data and the real DDL for the table and the real execution plans.

Comment: Aha, this could be potential data corruption! I haven't even imagined it that way. Thank you for the hint! I will close this question.

Comment: @pitachips . . . Perhaps more prosaically the data changed between the two queries.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries are correct, they just do not ask for the same thing. The 1st query asks for all id values with a specified premiumYn value (Y). The 2nd query asks for id and premiumYn for a given set of id values, without regard to the value of premiumYn. If you want the 2nd query to also return the a specified id values for only a specified premiumYn value then you must include both in the WHERE clause.

```
select id, premiumyn 
  from user
 where premiumyn= 'Y'
   and id in ( 12345678 
             , 23456789
             , 34567890
             );
```